# Can you name a Puppeteer generated PDF without saving it?

Tags: node.js, pdf, puppeteer

I just got a PDF generator working using Puppeteer.

I have a button on my page that sends a request to my API, which in turn calls my middleware function that actually creates the PDF. The PDF is sent back to the browser. A link is created and clicked (using JS) to display the PDF in a new tab.

When the PDF is displayed in the browser, the name is a seemingly random GUID.

I would like to name the file without saving it. Looking through the docs, I can see where the `path` variable can be set, but that will automatically save the file.

Here is the function that sends the data to the server and receives/displays the PDF in a new tab.

```
function printPDF() {
    var url = aName + "/api/PrintPDF/";
    var headers = []
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', url);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('DomainName', domainName);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(event) {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            const blob = new Blob([this.response], { type: 'application/pdf' })
            const link = document.createElement('a')
            link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
            link.target = "_blank";
            //link.download = `your-file-name.pdf` //Works, but auto-saves the PDF
            //link.title = "Test Name"; //does not change name
            //link.id = "Test ID" //does not change name
            //link.name = "Test"//does not change name
            link.click()
        }
    }
    var data = JSON.stringify({ barcodeAppData: JSON.stringify(barcodeAppData) });
    xhr.send(data);
}
```

Middleware Function

```
exports.printPDF = async function(url) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
    await page.evaluate(() => {
        document.querySelector('.pdfShow').style.display = "block"
    });
    await page.addStyleTag({
        content: `.pdfHide { display: none }; `
    });
    const pdf = await page.pdf({ printBackground: true, preferCSSPageSize: true });

    await browser.close();

    return pdf
};
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out?